# Any words that mean "relating to the action of reading"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing an e-mail and I wanted to have a bit of a cheeky closing, so I wrote:

> I apologize for taking up so much of your "..." time

I had originally wanted to use a word that would roughly describe the quality of the time as having been spent on reading, so something like "reading time". However, I could not seem to find any word that would correspond to what I was trying to express and I couldn't of much far than 'literary', which is not really what I was looking for.

I'm looking for a word that roughly means 'of or related to the act of reading' or just 'of or related to reading' but so far I have had no luck. If anyone knows such a word or something similar, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you :)

Comment: *Reading time* works for your purposes as long as you face that the line takes up even more  time apologizing for taking up time. Like a lecturer announcing that "My remarks will be *brief*".

Comment: "couldn't of much far"?

Comment: Perhaps "study time".

Comment: [None of these synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/reading) sounds as good as *reading*.

Comment: What is the person reading? Books? Magazines? Student essays? Sales reports?

Comment: Adjectives – including present participial adjectives – were often traditionally defined thus: '_as, like, or pertaining to N_' (N the relevant noun / nominal ing-form). Ing-forms used before a noun that are not seen as adjectives could be similarly defined. So 'reading' is fine for 'pertaining to reading'. Compare 'reading glasses'. More precisely, one means 'set aside for [or intended for] reading', the other 'made to facilitate reading'.

Comment: Technically, you may be taking up their time, but not their reading time. The person may have to do, or want to do, their full amount of reading for the day, and your email is just adding to it--not subtracting.

Comment: *Thank you for lending your eyeballs.*

Comment: @DjinTonic I'm not necessarily looking for a word for this specific situation. The email was just an example to ground my example, but my question was generally regarding a word related to reading. The context is kind of trivial, I'm just looking for a word.

Comment: Can you think of other contexts where you might use this word? "reading time" means "time that would be spent reading".

Comment: @Barmar, I was thinking of something like "literary endeavors" but for reading. So basically efforts regarding reading could perhaps be described as "X endeavors" but I can't quite find the word. "Reading endeavors" sounds kind of silly and the more colloquial 'reading' isn't really in harmony with the more formal/fancy 'endeavor', at least in my opinion.

Comment: So it would include things like peer-reviewing journal articles and writing book reviews? I'm not sure there's an encompassing term for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an erudite adjective that refers to reading, there is nothing common, but one rarer word is **[lectional](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lectional)**, from Latin *legō*, "I read". It is very obscure and obsolete except in specific senses, and not found in most dictionaries. But it means pertaining to reading or readings.

It is most commonly used, as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lection#English) says, when referring to "a reading of a religious text; a lesson to be read in church etc."

However you can find it used in specific technical contexts to mean pertaining to reading. One example is "lectional marks" or "lectional signs", symbols in old texts that act as an aid to readers (marking breaks in text, changes of speaker, etc). Here's an example of a work discussing them:

- "VIII. Lectional signs and editorial technique ancient and modern",
  *Bulletin of the Institute of Classical Studies*, Volume 33, Issue Supplement_54, February 1986, Pages 90–93, https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-5370.1986.tb01378.x

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the type of word that I was looking for. For future reference, how can I find such obscure words? Are there specific types of resources/books that cover words like these? Any websites or dictionaries perhaps?